# What is the best way to convert nested list to polars dataframe

Tags: python, python-polars

I am converting a list to polars dataframe below. But still missing few columns in the dataframe i.e. name, fame etc. How to add those? Also, it there a better way out?

```
import polars as pl

list_sample = [
    {
        'name': 'A',
        'fame': 0,
        'data': {
            'date': ['2021-01-01', '2021-02-01', '2021-03-01'],
            'credit_score': [800, 890, 895],
            'spend': [1500, 25000, 2400],
            'average_spend': 5000
        }
    },
    {
        'name': 'B',
        'fame': 1,
        'data': {
            'date': ['2022-01-01', '2022-02-01', '2022-03-01'],
            'credit_score': [2800, 390, 8900],
            'spend': [15000, 5000, 400],
            'average_spend': 3000
        }
    }
]

rows = []

for item in list_sample:
    date = item['data']['date']
    credit_score = item['data']['credit_score']
    spend = item['data']['spend']
    rows.extend(list(zip(date, credit_score, spend)))

df = pl.DataFrame(rows)
```

Comment: what is your expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a dataframe from it directly:

```
pl.DataFrame(list_sample)
```

```
shape: (2, 3)
┌──────┬──────┬───────────────────────────────────┐
│ name ┆ fame ┆ data                              │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---                               │
│ str  ┆ i64  ┆ struct[4]                         │
╞══════╪══════╪═══════════════════════════════════╡
│ A    ┆ 0    ┆ {["2021-01-01", "2021-02-01", "2… │
│ B    ┆ 1    ┆ {["2022-01-01", "2022-02-01", "2… │
└──────┴──────┴───────────────────────────────────┘
```

You can [`.unnest()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.unnest.html#polars.DataFrame.unnest) the struct columns and [`.explode()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.explode.html#polars.DataFrame.explode) the list columns:

```
(pl.DataFrame(list_sample) 
   .unnest('data')
   .explode('date', 'credit_score', 'spend') 
)
```

```
shape: (6, 6)
┌──────┬──────┬────────────┬──────────────┬───────┬───────────────┐
│ name ┆ fame ┆ date       ┆ credit_score ┆ spend ┆ average_spend │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---        ┆ ---          ┆ ---   ┆ ---           │
│ str  ┆ i64  ┆ str        ┆ i64          ┆ i64   ┆ i64           │
╞══════╪══════╪════════════╪══════════════╪═══════╪═══════════════╡
│ A    ┆ 0    ┆ 2021-01-01 ┆ 800          ┆ 1500  ┆ 5000          │
│ A    ┆ 0    ┆ 2021-02-01 ┆ 890          ┆ 25000 ┆ 5000          │
│ A    ┆ 0    ┆ 2021-03-01 ┆ 895          ┆ 2400  ┆ 5000          │
│ B    ┆ 1    ┆ 2022-01-01 ┆ 2800         ┆ 15000 ┆ 3000          │
│ B    ┆ 1    ┆ 2022-02-01 ┆ 390          ┆ 5000  ┆ 3000          │
│ B    ┆ 1    ┆ 2022-03-01 ┆ 8900         ┆ 400   ┆ 3000          │
└──────┴──────┴────────────┴──────────────┴───────┴───────────────┘
```

You can add `.cast()` and [`.str.to_date()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.str.to_date.html#polars.Expr.str.to_date)

```
(pl.DataFrame(list_sample) 
   .unnest('data')
   .explode('date', 'credit_score', 'spend') 
   .with_columns(
      pl.col('fame').cast(pl.Int8),
      pl.col('date').str.to_date()
   )
)
```

```
shape: (6, 6)
┌──────┬──────┬────────────┬──────────────┬───────┬───────────────┐
│ name ┆ fame ┆ date       ┆ credit_score ┆ spend ┆ average_spend │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ ---        ┆ ---          ┆ ---   ┆ ---           │
│ str  ┆ i8   ┆ date       ┆ i64          ┆ i64   ┆ i64           │
╞══════╪══════╪════════════╪══════════════╪═══════╪═══════════════╡
│ A    ┆ 0    ┆ 2021-01-01 ┆ 800          ┆ 1500  ┆ 5000          │
│ A    ┆ 0    ┆ 2021-02-01 ┆ 890          ┆ 25000 ┆ 5000          │
│ A    ┆ 0    ┆ 2021-03-01 ┆ 895          ┆ 2400  ┆ 5000          │
│ B    ┆ 1    ┆ 2022-01-01 ┆ 2800         ┆ 15000 ┆ 3000          │
│ B    ┆ 1    ┆ 2022-02-01 ┆ 390          ┆ 5000  ┆ 3000          │
│ B    ┆ 1    ┆ 2022-03-01 ┆ 8900         ┆ 400   ┆ 3000          │
└──────┴──────┴────────────┴──────────────┴───────┴───────────────┘
```

Comment: This answers the question. Followup: Any way to enforce a custom dtype for example fame uses i64 but would want to use i8, date is str would want date type.

Comment: You can convert them after creation if that's what you mean? I've added an example.

Comment: cool, totally unrelated. Does it use lazy execution or eager? How to find that?

Comment: You can use `pl.LazyFrame()` if you want.